# PDF text edit/update with python in proper way

Tags: python, pypdf

I have a PDF file and I want to change some important section, only text.

In my PDF, there is a name 'HART'. I want to edit it into 'myname'

Here is PDF link: [PDF FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rDWFm4rtdnvr-uCvloWLaEkfjIeK_6v2/view?usp=sharing)

I am using pyPDF2 but no problem if you can solve with any other module.

can anyone help me in this case?

My Code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader 
from pdfrw import PdfReader 

def get_pdf_info(path): pdf = PdfReader(path) 
    #print(pdf.keys()) 
    print(pdf.Info) 
    print(pdf.Root.keys()) 
    #print('PDF has {} pages'.format(len(pdf.pages))) 

if name == 'main': 
    get_pdf_info('editpy.pdf')
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

from pdfrw import PdfReader


def get_pdf_info(path):
    pdf = PdfReader(path)

    #print(pdf.keys())
    print(pdf.Info)
    print(pdf.Root.keys())
    #print('PDF has {} pages'.format(len(pdf.pages)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_pdf_info('editpy.pdf')